# IF Condition with 'AND' and 'OR' Operator in ADF Pipeline Expression Builder

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am making an API call in Azure Function and retrieving values for 7 diff attributes.
Out of these 7 attributes 6 of the attributes return Boolean value,whereas one attribute Requested Timestamp will either return Null or some timestamp value.

I am using an IF condition to validate the values of these attributes.The six attributes which returns value 'TRUE' or 'FALSE' I am using equals ('TRUE',.output)
Since the Requested Timestamp attribute might return null or a timestamp value i tried using NULLSAFE operator but its giving me an error.
Please find my complete expression below.

```
@and(and(and(and(and(and(
    equals('TRUE', activity('SourceSystemFlags').output['SAP Flags']['LOCKED?']),
    equals('TRUE', activity('SourceSystemFlags').output['SAP Flags']['DATAHUB READY'])),
    equals('TRUE', activity('SourceSystemFlags').output['SAP Flags']['REQUEST DATA NOW'])),
    equals('FALSE', activity('SourceSystemFlags').output['SAP Flags']['NDP IMPORTING'])),
    equals('TRUE', activity('SourceSystemFlags').output['SAP Flags']['TRANSACTIONAL DATA IMPORT FLAG'])),
    equals('FALSE' ,activity('SourceSystemFlags').output['SAP Flags']['SRC SYNC ACTIVE'])),
or (activity('SourceSystemFlags').output?,['SAP Flags']['REQUESTED TIMESTAMP']))
```

I am getting an error saying 'and' is a primitive and doesn't support nested properties.
Any kind of help to resolve this problem is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

These are hard to find errors, but you have a typo in the OR and a misplaced closing parenthesis. Try this:

```
@and(
    and(
        and(
            and(
                and(
                    and(equals('TRUE',activity('SourceSystemFlags').output['SAP Flags']['LOCKED?'])
                        ,equals('TRUE',activity('SourceSystemFlags').output['SAP Flags']['DATAHUB READY']))
                    ,equals('TRUE', activity('SourceSystemFlags').output['SAP Flags']['REQUEST DATA NOW'])
                    )
                ,equals('FALSE', activity('SourceSystemFlags').output['SAP Flags']['NDP IMPORTING'])
            )
            ,equals('TRUE', activity('SourceSystemFlags').output['SAP Flags']['TRANSACTIONAL DATA IMPORT FLAG'])
        ),equals('FALSE' ,activity('SourceSystemFlags').output['SAP Flags']['SRC SYNC ACTIVE'])
        ,or(activity('SourceSystemFlags').output['SAP Flags']['REQUESTED TIMESTAMP'])
    )
)
```

It is completely fine to format the code like this for readability, it does not all have to be on one line.